# Excel 2010 - Find Records With Last Date Prior to Given Time

Tags: filter, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet with a list of users and all the timestamps for their logins for the past two years.  I want to find all the users who have not logged in for specified periods of time -- say, not within the past month, not within the past two months.

How can I do this?

The data are in two columns, user ID and login date/time stamps.

```
user1 11/3/10 13:21
user1 1/3/11 12:54
user1 1/23/11 9:58
user2 10/2/10 10:13
...
```

Date and time are a single column.

I can see how to find, say users that logged in prior to a particular date but not how to exclude at the same time, those who logged in after that date.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

mp

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a UDF that would be very helpful in this situation:

http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/find-nth.htm

It will work basically like a VLOOKUP, but is not limited to only finding the first instance of something. For example, to find the date of the last instance of a certain user (assuming the reference sheet is all in chronological order), build a spreadsheet with 3 columns, one with a unique list of usernames, one with the total number of occurrences, and the third column with the Nth_occurrence formula to return the date of the last occurrence.

number of occurances formula:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,A1)
```

formula for third column:

```
=Nth_Occurrence(Sheet1!A:A,A1,B1,0,1)
```

You can then compare this last date to see if it falls within the last week, month, etc.

Of course, if you are against UDFs, you could accomplish nearly the same goal by re-sorting your sheet in reverse-chronological order and then just using VLOOKUP, which would of course only find the first instance (which would be the most recent). But this is not nearly as smooth ;-)